# Getting gps coordinates when mouse is moved

Tags: google-maps-flutter

I need to get the GPS coordinates of the mouse pointer and keep this info updated with mouse move.
Using the MouseRegion widget I can get the coordinates in pixels (even if there is a padding I cannot get rid of). But then how can I translate pixel coordinates into GPS coordinates?

GoogleMap widget has onTap event. Also, it has onCameraMove event that enable me to gather the current zoom level and target.
But there is no onMouseChange event...